# File exceeds the defined ini size when using iframe

Tags: php, zend-framework, iframe, file-upload

I am using fancy box iframe to display my page which has the file upload button. when i click form submit i got the "File exceeds the defined ini size". i checked some of links under google and stackoverflow. But not able to find. I have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form. Following is my code

```
public function createForm($data = array())
    {
        $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);
        $this->setEncType(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);
                $this->setAttrib('id', 'createsub');
            $this->setAction(
              $this->getView()->getHelper('url')->url(array(
                'controller' => 'test',
                'action'     => 'create'
              ))
            );  

        $this->setDecorators(array(
              'Description',
              'FormElements',
              'Form'
        ));

        $fnameNotEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
        $fnameNotEmpty->setMessage('Name cannot be empty.');
        $fnameStrlen = new Zend_Validate_StringLength(1, 20);

        $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name', array(
          'label' => 'Name:',
          'value' => '',
          'class' => 'text-size text',
          'tabindex' => '1',
          'required' => true,
          'validators' => array(
                array($fnameNotEmpty, true),
                array($fnameStrlen, true)
          ),
      'decorators' => $this->requiredElementDecorators,
      'description' => '<img src="../../'.$baseurl.'/images/star.png" alt="required" />',
          'filters' => array('StringTrim')
        ));
        $this->addElement($name);

....         .....           .....

        $brochure = new Zend_Form_Element_File('brochure', array(
          'label' => 'Brochure:*',
          'value'   => '',
          'class' => 'text-size text',
          'tabindex' => '3',
          'required' => true,
          'filters' => array('StringTrim')
        ));
        $this->addElement($brochure);




            $submit = $this->createElement('button','addtbtn',array('class'=>'Test','label'=>'Create'));
            $submit->setIgnore(true);
    $this->addElement($submit);
        return $this;
    }
```

Also if i did not use iframe, I can able to upload my image...Very Strange.

I make the validation using Ajax by following code ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Path="<?php echo $this->eurl; ?>"
$(function()
{
    vReg=0
    $("#addtbtn").click(function()
    {
        if(vReg == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
        var url = 'validateform';
        var data = {};
        $("input").each(function()
        {
            data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        });
        $("select").each(function()
        {
            data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        });
        $("textarea").each(function()
        {
            data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        });
                $.post(url,data,function(resp)
        {
            vError=""
            for(id in resp){
                oResp=resp[id];
                for(key in oResp){
                    vError +=oResp[key]+"\n"
                }
            }
            if(vError == ''){
                vReg=1
                                 $("#createform").attr('target','_top');
                 $("#createform").submit();
                                return true;
            }
            else{
                                $("#createform").attr('target','_self');
                alert(vError)
                                return false;
                            }
        },'json');

        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Also Has the following function in my controller

```
    public function validateformAction()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();

        $p      = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Test();
        $p      = $p->getData();

        foreach($p AS $k => $v)
        {
            $p[$v['catid']] = $v['name'];
        }

        $form = new Admin_Model_Form_SubTest();
        $f = $form->createForm(array('parents' => $p));
    $f->isValid($this->_getAllParams());
    $json = $f->getMessages();
    echo Zend_Json::encode($json);
}
```

So this will call the function which i gave on the top of the post and do the validation and return the error.But here i always getting `"File exceeds the defined ini size "` What I done wrong this code.

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) setting in your .ini file(s). That's where this error comes from.

Comment: Thanks But Even i click form with out upload file,i get the message. Also i checked with upload_max_filesize , image size is smaller than  upload_max_filesize.

Comment: Also if i did not use iframe, I can able to upload my image...Very Strange

Comment: Shouldn't be any difference between an upload in an iframe from an upload in a regular page - it's still just an http upload. May want to check what's being received on the server by dumping out $_FILES.

Answer (score 0):

When you call .val() on your file input, you get the path of the file you have selected, while your validator will be expecting the file itself, hence the strange error. Most people opt to skip file inputs when doing ajax validation, and just check it on submit.